# Is there a way to see all android log messages from inside an app at runtime?

Tags: android, parsing, runtime, logging

I would like to parse all logmessages (from other apps too) from inside my app at runtime. Is this somehow possible ?

Just to clarify, I want to get the logmessages without the use of eclipse, adb or any other external tool but my app only.

PS: I am using Android 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read logs.. I do something like,

```
String readLogs()
 {
 StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
 try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        log.append(line);
      }
     } catch (IOException e) {
       return null;
    }
 return log.toString();
 }
```

In manifest file add this permission..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Comment: You can add any more parameters to the logcat command string for filters specific TAG.

Comment: Thank you. Except for the part where 'log' cannot be resolved because its defined in the try-block it works nicely.

Comment: @HardCoder - Sorry, just initialize it before try catch.